# Chances finding an enchanted fishing rod?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there an enchanted fishing rod on 360 version? Would it be better to fish in river, pond, or ocean?

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft wiki says that a *treasure* item has a 5% chance of dropping. In that 5% 16.67% of those will be a enchanted fishing rod. This means that `5% * 16% = 0.8335%` giving it a **0.8335%** chance of dropping.

Comment: Anyway to add lure on an existing rod

Comment: Yes, through the use of an enchanting table. [this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchantment_Table) shows you how to make it.

Comment: I have the table just don't know how to add lure. I think that link is for the PC version with the enchanting table

Comment: It is random, when you put in the rod, there will be three options, they will each give a different enchantment, the more levels you spend (indicated by the small number) the more powerful it is. There are two enchantments that you can get on the fishing rod, Luck of the Sea (increases treasure finds) and Lure (increases rate of fish bites). One (or maybe two) will be applied to the rod.